# C# winform: communation between winform and usercontrol

Tags: c#, button, user-controls

I want to develop a custom button which contain a properity that can be changed dynamics according to the content. This button would be used more that once in the same form.

for example: the custom button contain a string: str. if we want the button update the database, we just need to set the string in the mainform: str= "update mytable ****". if we want the delete function, we just need to set the string into: str="delete from my table....." in the main form.

Can you give me an example?  I am a newer in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy to achieve this you just need to override button class of the .net framwork and need to write you own code

you can check this blog post wheer i did the same thing for the textbox : [Enhanced Textbox Control](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/04/enhanced-textbox-control.html)

Comment: string sqlstr;
public string SqlStr
{get { return sqlstr; } set { sqlstr = value; } }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //(or use override void OnClick(EventArgs e) )
{base.OnClick(e);  MessageBox.Show(sqlstr);}

Comment: how to overide it?  override void OnClick(EventArgs e) in the usercontrol?  I have try this but fail

Comment: you just need to put putblic override void onClick(..) this will orverride chek the article where i override on method....

Comment: can I realize it in this      string sqlstr;
        [Description("SQL STRING")]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "")]
        public string SqlStr
        {
            get { return sqlstr; }
            set { sqlstr = value; }

        }

        //private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        protected override void  OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClick(e);
            MessageBox.Show(this.sqlstr);
            string str = sqlstr.Trim();
             MessageBox.Show(str);
           
        }

Comment: is that pranayamr@gmail.com  your email.  i have try to ask you some question by email. Yet it seems that something wrong

Comment: @Beta Hu - on this id i can talk with you after 10 hr, right now not avialbe on that id

Answer (score 0):

You can create the public properties in the usercontrol and also public methods, that will be accessible from your form. Then you can allocate the value to property and call the appropriate method to execute the database tranascation statement.

Comment: string sqlstr; I have try this: in the usercontrol: public string SqlStr { get { return sqlstr; } set { sqlstr = value; } } private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) {base.OnClick(e); MessageBox.Show(sqlstr);}  while in the main form:  private void userControl11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {userControl11.SqlStr="....";}    if there are two usercontrol in the same form, only one of them can show out the value sqlstr, others would show nothing

Comment: your email pranayamr@gmail.com?

Comment: its Pranay's Email, Mine is bhavikgoyal@gmail.com